# How do I find the nearest tbody then loop through its rows and hide them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that is split up into several tbody's. The first row in each tbody has a button which will be used to hide all other rows in this tbody apart from the row with the button in it.

Not sure how to achieve this.

My HTML :

```
<table>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td><button class="hide_button_main"> x </button></td>
           <td>Label</td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Zone 1</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Zone 2</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>Zone 3</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr> 
       <tr>
            <td>Zone 4</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr> 
   </tbody>
```

Rows with zones 1 to 4 would be hidden but not the row with the label in it

My Jquery:

```
     $('.hide_button_main').click(function(e) {

   // var rows = $(this).closest('tbody').find('tr').length;

    var rows = $(this).closest('tbody');

        rows.each(function() {

      alert('1');

    });


});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this

```
$('.hide_button_main').click(function(e){
    $(this).closest('tbody').hide();
});
```

or if you want to hide tbody child do like this

```
$('.hide_button_main').click(function(e){
    $(this).closest('tbody').find('tr').hide();
});
```

Comment: "...hide all other rows in this tbody apart from the row with the button in it. "

Comment: thanks, i've edited my comment, i'm not good enough in english :D

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('.hide_button_main').click(function(e){
    $(this).closest('tr').siblings().hide(); // hide all except self
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it

```
$('table').on('click', '.hide_button_main', function(e) {
    var target = $(e.currentTarget);
    var row = target.closest('tr');
    console.log('console', target, row, row.siblings())
    row.siblings().hide();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qFAc8/)

Here we used delegated event registration model using jQuery.on. which is recommended if we have a lot of elements to which the event handler has to be attached.

Answer (score 0):

He wants to hide all siblings rows, so:

```
$('.hide_button_main').click(function (e) {
   var $currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
   var $otherRows = $currentRow.siblings();
   $otherRows.hide();
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/NeXMh/1/

**EDIT**

When working with several tables, then work with single event handler:

```
$('table').on(click, '.hide_button_main', (function (e) {
   var $currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
   var $otherRows = $currentRow.siblings();
   $otherRows.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide all the rows other than the first...

```
  $('.hide_button_main').click(function(e){
        $(this).closest('tbody').find('tr:not(:first)').hide();
    });
```